# Exporting CouchDb data to CBLite

Tags: android, couchdb, couchdb-futon, couchbase-lite

I'm trying to implement the pre-build database concept of couch base in android application. I have a couchdb data that i need to convert to cblite file, so that i can put the file in assets of my application. This will help me to init the application with existing data and reduce the time of launching the app.

Currently I am replicating the data in a test android application -> copying the .cblite file from application databases in device -> pasting it in assets folder of my production app.

The mentioned process is very long and not feasible for me. Is there any other method or Desktop/Browser tool that can be used to convert/export the data to .cblite file directly.

Thanks!

Comment: Reading several times your scenario I wonder why you ask `tool that can be used to convert/export the data to .cblite file directly.`  Where you also said `replicating the data in a test android application` which to my understanding means 'exporting to a .cblite file'. You see I do not understand this. And I wonder why you need two types of database.

Comment: Sorry if I was unable to explain my issue better. To implement Pre-build database concept, I need to place the cblite file in assets folder of android application. I have a huge set of data on couchdb server. My question is, how I can export/generate .cblite file from couchdb server directly (without an android application in between)?

Comment: It seems there is no other method for now. I had to rely on the Android application for the conversion. for more information on this, follow the discussion at: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mobile-couchbase/oqrwkwYXJvw